# entropy change when reading from /dev/urandom vs /dev/random

Tags: linux, random, entropy

I noticed that when reading from `/dev/random`, I have a very real impact on the entropy available on my linux box.

(reading from `/proc/system/kernel/random/entropy_avail`),

Yet when reading from `/dev/urandom`, (I understand seeded by real entropy but actually a CSPRNG), I can generate high quality entropy data, but my `entropy_avail` doesn't drop...

How is this possible, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's intended behavior. You should probably use urandom since you'll have lots of entropy starvation issues if you try to use random for anything serious.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom).

Comment: thanks but how can /dev/urandom provide high quality entropy without actually USING entropy? @user

Comment: It uses seed data from /dev/random and uses a (probably) secure CSPRNG to generate arbitrary amounts of data from it. I believe it gets periodically reseeded from system entropy, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: thanks if you want to add this as an answer, I will mark as correct @user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/urandom` uses a CSPRNG (Chacha20 last time I checked) to generate a stream of random data from an initial seed and allows the user to read an arbitrary number of bits from it. `/dev/random` pulls data out of a random pool that needs to be replenished.

It is possible to read from `/dev/urandom` before the system has enough entropy to provide a secure stream of data, in which case the kernel log should show a warning about an uninitialized read from it. If this is a concern, for example in embedded systems, then you'll need to use a hardware random number generator to generate additional entropy before you let programs start using it.

Provided the system gathered enough entropy, you'll get cryptographically secure random data from `urandom` and information theoretically secure data from `random`. If you're using a non-information-theoretically-secure encryption scheme or you're not generating vast quantities of encryption keys, then you might as well just use `urandom`.

You shouldn't read from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` directly since the kernel exposes a nice `getrandom` system call that you can use in your programs, and it will help you avoid some pitfalls when trying to read from the character devices directly.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom) has additional details about the differences between the two RNG devices.

Comment: @Woodstock No problem. I'll add in a bit about potential issues with low entropy reads from `urandom`.